# Insufficient roles/credentials for operation when using ensemble-add in JBoss Fuse 6.2

Tags: java, fuseesb, jbossfuse, fabric8

I am using JBoss Fuse 6.2 and trying to create an ensemble with 3 servers. The servers are 3 physical servers running Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and installed with JDK 1.8.0_60.

I renamed the root containers in etc/system.properties to root1, root2 and root3 respectively and made sure no users were configured in etc/users.properties on all servers.

I then started fuse on server1 and ran the command

```
fabric:create --new-user admin --new-user-password admin --new-user-role Administrator --zookeeper-password admin --resolver manualip --manual-ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --wait-for-provisioning
```

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx being the IP of server1

I then started fuse on server2 and server3 and ran the following command:

```
fabric:join --zookeeper-password admin server1:2181
```

That all worked fine and output of `container-list` on server1 was

```
[id]    [version]  [type]  [connected]  [profiles]              [provision status]
root1*  1.0        karaf   yes          fabric                  success
                                        fabric-ensemble-0000-1
                                        jboss-fuse-full
root2   1.0        karaf   yes          fabric                  success
root3   1.0        karaf   yes          fabric                  success
```

Then when I run the command to add root2 and root3 to the ensemble:

```
fabric:ensemble-add root2 root3
```

I get this error:

Error executing command: java.lang.SecurityException: Insufficient roles/credentials for operation

I found something resembling this issue in the JBoss Fuse issue tracker: [ENTESB-3530](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ENTESB-3530)

Anyone have any suggestions to make this work?

Comment: The issue you linked stats that with different jdk he was able to make the esemble work. have you try with a jdk 1.7 ?

Comment: I have a similar issue... Try to not use the `--new-user-role Administrator` parameter in the `fabric:create` command. It appears the roles' name in Fuse 6.2 is different now. Let Fuse fabric assign the default one.

Comment: That worked @Tuelho! Could you write that as an answer instead of a comment? Then I will accept it as answer.
Do you know how I can see what roles Fuse have assigned to the created admin user?

Comment: You may find some information here, maybe https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.2/html/Migration_Guide/ESBMigrationIntro.html

Comment: Hi @npeder,
The Fuse 6.2 implements the RBAC now. There are a lot of `.cfg` files (located in `FUSE_HOME/etc/auth`). Take a look in the [security guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.2/html/Security_Guide/RBAC.html). IIRC there are a new admin role called `admin` you have to assign to the admin users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to not use the `--new-user-role Administrator` parameter in the `fabric:create` command. It appears the roles' names in Fuse 6.2 are different now. Let Fuse fabric assign the default one.

See the what `fabric:create --help` says:

```
--new-user-role
  The role of the new user. The option refers to karaf user (ssh, http, jmx). 
  (defaults to _g_:admin)
```